# Logstash date ISO8601 convert

Tags: date, logstash

I want to convert logstash date type to this type `2015-12-03 03:01:00` and `[message][3] - [message][1]`

Date match doesn't work, how can I do?

Or `%{[message][0]}` expression is right or not.

```
filter {
    multiline {
       .............
    }
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
        overwrite => ["message"]
    }
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message", "\n", " "]
        split => ["message", " "]
    }
    date {
        match => [ "%{[message][0]}","ISO8601"} ]
    }
}
```

Message output like this:

```
"message" => [
[0] "2015-12-03T01:33:22+00:00"
[1]
[2]
[3] "2015-12-03T01:33:24+00:00"
]
```

Comment: I'm lost. Please edit this question to make your problem and desired output clear, using legible grammar and a notable lack of boldface or large fonts. We can't help you if we can't understand you.

Comment: Please post the sample input?

Comment: Your grok{} filter is doing nothing but wasting CPU time.  There's no reason to take [message], match everything, and put it back into [message].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is:

```
2015-12-03T01:33:22+00:00\n\n2015-12-03T01:33:24+00:00
```

You can grok that without split:

```
match => { message, "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:string1}\\n\\n%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:string2}" }
```

You can then use the date{} filter with string1 or string2 as input.